# What name do i use to connect to a server socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

I am writing a telnet like program in java using the server socket and socket classes.  This is my current code for the client program.  The user types in the server name and the port they would like to connect on.

```
static Socket getSocket()
{
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("What server do you want to connect to on which port?");
        String info = sc.nextLine();
        String host = info.split(" ")[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(info.split(" ")[1]);

        try 
        {
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            return new Socket(ip, port);
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("The host is unknown.");
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Network error.");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried connecting on localhost, and it worked.  Then i tried connecting with my friend on a remote computer using the ip address as the network name and it did not work giving an exception.  What name do i use to connect to a remote server.

Comment: What Exception do you get ?

Comment: i dont have the exception it was on his remote computer, i was running the server on my computer and i cant contact him right now

Comment: Probably you has to define a forward rule in your WAN router.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your friend [your **remote** IP address](http://www.whatismyip.com/).

Comment: Have you configured the NAT in your home router? Telling it that a request to port X must be redirected to your PC? Also, check the terms of contract with your ISP.